# Tomcat9 not starting after installation on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: tomcat, 21.04

I installed Tomcat 9 using `sudo apt-get install tomcat9` then de-installed tomcat9 using `sudo apt-get --purge remove tomcat9`. I then proceeded to reinstall tomcat9 using the `apt-get install` command. After the re-installation Tomcat did not start, so I tried to start it using s`udo service tomcat9 start` and found the following error in /var/log/tomcat/catalina.out:

```
[2021-04-26 16:21:21] [info] /usr/libexec/tomcat9/tomcat-start.sh: 25: exec: /usr/share/tomcat9/bin/catalina.sh: not found.
```

Please assist.

Comment: I've seen situations where `catalina.sh` exists, but is not marked as executable. Have you confirmed the file is in the `/usr/share/tomcat9/bin` directory? If so, is it executable?

Comment: @matigo The entire bin directory is missing.

Comment: If that's the case, you may want to double check the `CATALINA_BASE` and `CATALINA_HOME` environment variables are correct in your `/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service` file. They may be pointing to a location different from where you installed Tomcat9 

Comment: @matigo The `tomcat.service` file is not present in the `/etc/systemd/system` folder.

Comment: If that's the case, you may want to double-check that Tomcat is actually installed.

Comment: @matigo Tomcat installation is broken. The `/usr/share/tomcat9` directory exists.

Comment: When I reinstall Tomcat, I get the message: "Tomcat is already installed."